# mongodb when to close connections and when to make them persistent

Tags: django, mongodb, database-connection

I am writing a Django app using mongodb. For a simple GET request I need to get results from database for which I am making a connection in the HTTPRequestHandler. The db operation for the HTTPRequest isn't a heavy operation. Should I close the connection in that handler itself. Her is the code snippet.

```
def search(request):
    dbConnection = Connection('hostname', int('port-no'))
    ... made a small query to db. (not a heavy operation)
    dbConnection.close()
    return HTTPResponse(result)
```

Is this code doing the suitable job of connecting and closing connections. What I want to know is that is it fast in terms of performance. I want this "search" HTTPRequestHandler to work fast. If this is not the way to go, can someone please explain when and how should we close connections and when to make them persistent in mongo.

Comment: Connection opening is expensive. You should keep them open where appropriate. Don't know how it's done in Django, though.

Comment: can you please tell me how it is done in python in general.

Comment: No, I can't. I'm a ruby guy :)

Comment: My best guess it's that you can create the connection inside your settings.py and then import your settings when you need the connection

Comment: settings.py Ok, I will try that. How many connections should I make. Is there any way you approach to decide the number of connections you need.